# Xcode 4 Adding a Sub Project

Tags: xcode, project

I am looking at somebody else's project and they have another project embedded under 'Other Sources'.  When I click on the project it shows me the build settings etc, and I can expand all the source underneath.

I want to do the same thing, but when I drag an xcodeproj file into my project I don't get the build settings or any of the source shown like in this other project.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 112):

Just be sure that your added project is not open in another Xcode window.

BTW this is still valid with Xcode 7.2 beta.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference in 4.2.  I had one which I dragged from another open project which was included fine, though now I'm having the issue that it's just including the xcodeproj file.

Comment: This worked great in Xcode 4.3.1. I wish there was a warning when this happened, it's wildly frustrating.

Comment: In Xcode 4.3.2 they've added a lock, so a project cannot be open in two windows at the same time, even if not in different workspaces.

Comment: In latest Xcode (4.3.2 as of this comment), you can also right-click the project navigator, select "Add Files to MyApp", then select the xcodeproj file that you want to add.

Comment: Oh for the love of Cthulhu. I need an inanimate object to beat with a baseball bat when Xcode pulls shit like this.

Comment: Thank you! That was 15 minutes I'll never get back.

Comment: @Alphatrak: yes, that's another way to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Still the same problem in XCode 5 (preview).

Comment: OMG. so much time gets wasted on so silly things. Thanks a million @MacTeo

Comment: xcode 6.1  and this still works! it's shame we have to find it this way though!

Answer (score 51):

Sorry to revamp the old question, but I just got the absolute answer for this problem.... maybe this can help the other....

To add Sub-Project to current project, It just simply drag the `.xcodeproj` from finder to xcode, place it in your project...

**BUT**... there is something must be done before doing this.... **JUST OPEN ONE XCODE INSTANCE**.... So, close the other instance when dragging `.xcodeproj` to xcode....

If you drag it while opening few xcode instance (opening few project at once), the `.xcodeproj` that you dragged can't be expanded and not just what you want...

hope this can help the other....

Regards

Comment: If I remove/change location of subproject after adding the subproject to main project then the subproject and files are shown in red color. Should not we change location of subprojects?

Answer (score 0):

When you drag the new project to the source list in Xcode, make sure you drop it on top of the project header (the thing that you click to get to the build settings and targets).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This then asks me to create a new workspace, but the other project doesn't have a workspace and still manages to have the other project embedded within it.  Is this the same technique?

Comment: Not sure. I just tried it with one of my Xcode projects and it worked without any dialogs appearing. I would just try experimenting by dropping it in different places. Make sure to keep a backup though just in case.

Comment: Tried this again and still didn't work. In the end I had to make a duplicate copy of the directory containing the project and then when I dropped it, I could see everything.  It's like a project can only be a sub project of ONE other project?

Comment: @Ray, Yes, if you place the project at the same level as your main project, you need to create a new workspace. Make sure you have updated your main app for the (Build settings) "User Header Search Paths" and (Build Phases) Link Binary with Libraries. This is not perfect but at least it works.