# Xcode project inside project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm taking over some project of a colleague that is on holidays now.

Other projects have gone fine, but in this particular one, I have found a project inside a project, like using a framework I guess.

So what is the name of this technique?

[image: project inside project tree image]

How to insert and interact with it? just import?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are called cross project references.  From the link below:

> Cross-project references are a convenient way to create relationships
> between two separate Xcode projects.

One method of creating shared frameworks is using sub-projects.  You can also do it with single projects.  More here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html

Other links:

[Xcode 4 Adding a Sub Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784561/xcode-4-adding-a-sub-project)

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode Cross-project references**

[`cross-project references`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html) aka `project in project` aka `sub-project` aka `nested projects`.
This approach uses `Explicit dependency`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219025/4770877) [<sup>[How to setup]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836400/4770877)

> If you already have separate Xcode projects for your framework and application, you can take advantage of Xcode’s cross-project references to embed the framework in your application. Cross-project references are a convenient way to create relationships between two separate Xcode projects.

To define explicit dependencies between targets in separate project files, project files should be **nested**. This means that a target can set `explicit dependencies` of any other target within the same project file, or any nested child project file.

In XCode 4, the idea of `workspaces`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877) is supposed to supersede the functionality of XCode 3s `cross-project references`